# Does Selenium support Safari on Window 7?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, safaridriver

Selenium official site (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp) says **"SafariDriver requires Safari 5.1+ and only runs on OS X"**

whereas in the official Safari driver site (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver), I can see the below code -

```
private WebDriver driver = null;

private static boolean isSupportedPlatform() {
    Platform current = Platform.getCurrent();
    return Platform.MAC.is(current) || **Platform.WINDOWS.is(current);**
}

@Before
public void createDriver() {
    assumeTrue(isSupportedPlatform());
    driver = new SafariDriver();
}
```

So my question is does Selenium really support Safari on Windows OS ?

Comment: Did you try following the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5KGduKl6s6-YjZILWd1WEJMRUU/edit) ? It might be able to use Safari-Driver in windows system.

Comment: Yes, I did the exact steps but getting an error while starting the Safari driver.

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'

Comment: Did you try with other versions of Selenium (2.45) ? I guess it should work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out a bug in our documentation.

I've [made a push](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/www.seleniumhq.org/commit/d25695a9e8fd8ca5657de28b5d656400e845581a) to the site docs to include support for Windows, as well as noted the potential risk of running SafariDriver in Windows post 5.x.

Also, the official docs for Selenium have moved here:  https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/wiki

You should update all your links to include the GitHub wiki rather than the Google Code wiki

And to answer the question:

> does Selenium really support Safari on Windows OS ?

**Yes** it does.

Comment: Thanks for the update but is there I am getting an error while running the same code which is mentioned in the link provided by you.

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'

Safari browser start and I can see the message in that it is connected to Selenium WebDriver but then it closes and gives the above error.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has dropped the support for Safari on windows. Is as it hadn't existed. So even if you may get it to work it'll be an unreliable solution since the browser has been developed further for 5 long years since the latest windows version.

I would guess the driver may contain partial support for older versions, so it may have many errors on the implementation although it may contain some legacy code for windows. Also, there may have been some changes that were retrofitted for old versions in MacOS but weren't on Windows due to that situation.

The exact answer to what you're asking: you should ask the driver's authors; not sure if StackOverflow is the right place.